# PHP Best way to declare "global" variable in website

Tags: php

Here are the details, for now what i've done is that the webpage gets the `gameNo` from the URL and uses that for various functions. (I'm sending it there from various forms).

What i was wondering is how can i make it so that for example when a user picks a `gameNo` that will be set always until i unset it again. Either that is through the URL or somehow else.

Is something like this possible with `$_SESSION` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah instead of using `global` you could very well save it in a `$_SESSION` variable as this is a super-global array and it can be accessed under functions or nested functions too.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['gameNo']))
{
 $_SESSION['gameNo'] = $_REQUEST['gameNo'];
}

function showVal()
{
 echo $_SESSION['gameNo'];
}

showVal(); //"prints" the value of gameNo
```

Comment: will i be able to set a $_SESSION variable after he has logged in though?

Comment: Just made a simple example for your understanding. Yeah you can.

Comment: Putting it in the session is the best place, and you should be able to use $_SESSION for both login data _and_ application data.  The great thing about $_SESSION is that the user can't see it or change it - which is _not_ true of data sent as form components.  Be warned that if you send gameNo to the user to have them pass back, somebody's likely to start tampering with their GameNo.  Better to store _all_ taht kind of think directly in the session.  You know the gameNo anyway - they don't.

Comment: Yes that is true. I should make the changes at least on the parts that are important and more on the part of "sending" data to me. Thank you both for the clarification

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran would you mind explaining the change from `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` ?

Comment: I just made it as a `fail-safe` , Since I am unsure of how you are sending the `gameNo` parameter to this page. If it is through querystring you can very well use `$_GET` , If it's through form post , then you could use `$_POST` , The `$_REQUEST` satisfies both the criteria.